# Printing nested dicts to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am parsing certain text files and keeping track of a number of programs, software versions, and counts of those versions' occurrences, in the following structure:

```
{Excel: {'1.2.1':2, '2.1.1':55, '3.4.5':12},
 Adobe: {'1.1.1':4, '5.4.4':12, '4'3.3':8}[...]}
```

etc.

How can I print this neatly to CSV so that the output would look like this:

```
Program,Version,Count
Excel,1.2.1,2
Excel,2.1.1,55
Excel,3.4.5,12
Adobe,1.1.1,4
Adobe,5.4.4,12
Adobe,4.3.3,8
```

I have done a lot of searching and haven't been able to find exactly what I need. Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

Here is what I have tried, which I think comes close, but isn't right based on the output I get:

```
for prod,version in products.iteritems():
    for p in prod:
        for v in version:
            outfile.write('%s,%s,%d\n' % (p,v,version[v]))
```

where products is the name of the outer dict.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Well dicts have no order so there is no guarantee what output you would get

Comment: That is not a valid dictionary.

Comment: Added what I have currently tried (among some other things) - appreciate the help! Also, @grovesNL - what makes it invalid??

Comment: @DJMcCarthy12 If you had run your code, you'd know.

Comment: @PaulRooney - No need to get snippy, I've run the code probably over a hundred times now, with no issues until I try to print the dict in a neat CSV as I mentioned that I am trying to do, meaning the dict I am using is populating and being used fine. Perhaps I may have articulated it incorrectly in my question, sure. But some constructive advice would be better than short responses akin to yours.

Comment: Did the resulting format look something like this: "E,3.4.5,12 [...]"

When you write "for p in prod," you're iterating over each character of the string prod.

Comment: Apologies did not mean to seem 'snippy,' but too many people post code they obviously haven't run previously.  The issues with your dictionary are 1) The keys aren't valid literals. Meaning they would therefore have to be predefined variables for them to be valid 2) '4'3.3':8 would not be accepted as a valid string as it contains a quote.

Comment: @PaulRooney - Yeah, I meant to quote the keys, as they are indeed strings being read from a file, not variables, and the extra quote is indeed a typo. - KCzar, yep that's exactly what the output was looking like, one letter each line until I fixed the printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hacky way:

```
def print_csv_data(data):
  with open('my_output', 'w') as f:
     f.write('Program,Version,Count')
     for k, v in data.iteritems():
        for id, count in v.iteritems():
           f.write(k+','+id+','+count)
```

I'd recommend looking at the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) though for better use, as the above approach can easily break your document if your ids or program names contain commas.

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Program', 'Version', 'Count']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for k, v in data.iteritems():
        for id, count in v.iteritems():
           f.write({'Program':k, 'Version':id, 'Count':count})
```

Comment: Yesss this worked for what I needed. I didn't realize I had to do iteritems() in the inner dict as well - Doh! Thanks a lot man!